# Aggregating rmse and r2 in r

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, summarize

Here is a sample data as
data2:

```
 lvl   x  y
  0 20.099 21.2
100 21.133 21.4
250 20.866 21.6
500 22.679 21.8
750 22.737 22.1
  0 30.396 32.0
100 31.373 32.1
250 31.303 32.2
500 33.984 32.8
750 44.563 38.0
  0 22.755 18.5
100 23.194 18.8
250 23.263 20.5
500 23.061 27.9
750 25.678 36.4
```

I tried to get the rmse  and r2 for each level (lvl) by the following lines of codes:

```
data2 %>% group_by(lvl) %>% summarise_each(funs(rmse(data2$x~data2$y)))
```

and

```
summary(lm(data2$x,data2$y))$r.squared
```

respectively, and I got the following error message when calculating rmse:

> Error: argument "obs" is missing, with no default

and

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
    lvl         x         y
  <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     0 0.6639888 0.6639888
2   100 0.6639888 0.6639888
3   250 0.6639888 0.6639888
4   500 0.6639888 0.6639888
5   750 0.6639888 0.6639888
```

when calculating r2.

I wanted to aggregate the rmse and r2 for each level. In this case, I have only 5 levels. So the answer will look like 5 rows X 3 columns with column names `"lvl", "rmse", "r2" Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `summarise_each` summarise will do what you want.  If you prefer using dplyr here is a solution

```
data2 <-
data.frame(
  lvl = c(  0, 100, 250, 500, 750, 0, 100, 250, 500, 750, 0, 100, 250, 500, 750)
  ,x = c(
    20.099, 21.133, 20.866, 22.679, 22.737, 30.396, 31.373, 31.303, 33.984, 44.563, 22.755, 23.194, 23.263, 23.061, 25.678
  )
  ,y = c(21.2, 21.4, 21.6, 21.8, 22.1, 32.0, 32.1, 32.2, 32.8, 38.0, 18.5, 18.8, 20.5, 27.9, 36.4)
)

#install.packages("ModelMetrics")
library(ModelMetrics)

data2 %>%
  group_by(lvl) %>%
  summarise(
    RMSE = rmse(x, y)
    ,R2 = cor(x, y)^2
  )

## A tibble: 5 × 3
#    lvl     RMSE        R2
#  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     0 2.701237 0.8176712
#2   100 2.575982 0.8645350
#3   250 1.729888 0.9091029
#4   500 2.920640 0.7207692
#5   750 7.267279 0.4542507
```

Answer (score 1):

```
## split your data2 into a list by the levels of the factor and then use lapply
list_of_rsquared <- lapply(split(data2, data2$lvl), function (z) {
  summary(lm(x ~ y, data = z))$r.squared
}
)

## you will get a list of r.squared for each level . Now you can simply rbind the list of r.squared.
rsquared_vals <- do.call("rbind", list_of_rsquared)
```

You can use the same approach for RMSE. (I am assuming you have written a function called RMSE? because I am just using the formula you have above)

```
list_of_rmse <- lapply(split(data2, data2$lvl), function (z) { sqrt(mean((z$x - z$y)^2)) } )

rmse_vals <- do.call("rbind", list_of_rmse)
```

you can just `cbind` all three columns you need now:

```
cbind(data2$lvl, rsquared_vals, rmse_vals)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The rmse one didn't work. It gave me error message:  `Error in match(class(obs), c("integer", "numeric", "ts", "zoo")) : 
  argument "obs" is missing, with no default`. Can you please tweak it.

Comment: can you share your rmse function please?

Comment: I tried `data2 %>% group_by(lvl) %>% summarise_each(funs(rmse))` but it didn't work.

Comment: there is no function `rmse` predefined in `r`. read this: https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/hydroGOF/rmse.html to learn how to calculate RMSE and write a function for it first !

Comment: Yes, I saw that. It had the predefined `rmse` with the hydroGOF package. That is why I tried to use the `rmse` function. I also tried `list_of_rmse <- lapply(split(data2, data2$lvl), function (z) {
   z<-sqrt(mean(data2$x - data2$y)^2)
 }
 )` but I got a list of anwers: `$`0`
[1] 0.0144

$`100`
[1] 0.0144

$`250`
[1] 0.0144

$`500`
[1] 0.0144

$`750`
[1] 0.0144` Can you please tweak to get the final result. Thank you

Comment: well you can just do : `list_of_rmse <- lapply(split(data2, data2$lvl), function (z) { sqrt(mean(z$x - z$y)^2) } ) ` but i warn you - you are misinterpreting what RMSE is. The Error in RMSE = Actual - Predicted. You are just subtracting variable y from variable x and squaring that . It makes no sense. Please read and understand what RMSE means: https://heuristically.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/calculate-rmse-and-mae-in-r-and-sas/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128308/discussion-between-g1124e-and-vagabond).

Comment: You can edit the answer by adding a closing bracket in the first line of the codes for split function just before starting the function.

Comment: done ! and upvote the answer if it has worked out for you